# Quantity of entries

Tags: mysql, query

I have the below tables.The first one has posts with a foreign key to a category table.I'm looking for a query that gives me the amount of posts on every category.

The post table.

```
 select pstOccuId,pstTitle from job_post;
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| pstOccuId | pstTitle                                  |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
|         1 | Software Engineer Recruit                 |
|         1 | Web Developer Recruit                     |
|         7 | Saxophonist                               |
|         5 | Construction Company looking for plumber. |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

The category table.

```
 select occuDscr,occuId from occupation_field;
+---------------------+--------+
| occuDscr            | occuId |
+---------------------+--------+
| Software Engineer   |      1 |
| Economics           |      2 |
| Structural Engineer |      3 |
| Legal Advisors      |      4 |
| Plumbers            |      5 |
| Social Advisors     |      6 |
| Musicians           |      7 |
+---------------------+--------+
```

I'm looking for a query that gives me something like this.

```
+---------------------+--------+
| occuDscr            | amount |
+---------------------+--------+
| Software Engineer   |      2 |
| Plumbers            |      1 |
| Musicians           |      1 |
+---------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 select a.occuId, a.occuDscr, COUNT(b.pstOccuId ) AS `amount` 
 from occupation_field a
 INNER JOIN job_post b ON (b.pstOccuId = a.occuId)
 GROUP BY a.occuId;
```

If you want to display categories with 0 posts, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER`. Also, for other RDMS except mysql you have to `GROUP BY a.occuId, a.occuDscr` (Mysql lets you have just `GROUP BY a.occuId`

**UPDATE by @RolandoMySQLDBA**

The output of @a1ex07's query looks like this:

```
mysql> select a.occuId, a.occuDscr, COUNT(b.pstOccuId ) AS `amount`
    ->  from occupation_field a
    ->  INNER JOIN job_post b ON (b.pstOccuId = a.occuId)
    ->  GROUP BY a.occuId;
+--------+-------------------+--------+
| occuId | occuDscr          | amount |
+--------+-------------------+--------+
|      1 | Software Engineer |      2 |
|      5 | Plumbers          |      1 |
|      7 | Musicians         |      1 |
+--------+-------------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I can't make your query work.Can you explain what the use of the letters 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: Table aliases - you can use optional `AS` : `FROM occupation_field AS a` , `INNER JOIN ob_post AS b`. Also I fixed some misprints in my answers (wrong table names), it should work now

Comment: You still have the table spelled incorrectly. Change your `INNER JOIN ob_post` to `INNER JOIN job_post`.

Comment: Small correction `INNER JOIN job_post`.Now it works.I guess this `select occuDscr,count(pstOccuId) as 'amount' from occupation_field inner join job_post on (pstOccuId=occuId) group by occuId;` is the same.

Comment: Sorry for misprints :(

Comment: @a1ex07 : If it weren't for the misspelling, yours was the first correct answer. +1 !!!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    oc.occuDscr,pst.amount
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(1) amount,pstOccuId 
    FROM job_post GROUP BY pstOccuId) pst
    INNER JOIN occupation_field oc
    ON (pst.pstOccuId = oc.occuId)
ORDER BY
    pst.amount DESC,oc.occuDscr
;
```

Here is your sample data:

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists occupation_field;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> drop table if exists job_post;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> create table occupation_field
    -> (occuDscr varchar(50),
    -> occuId int not null auto_increment,
    -> primary key (occuId));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into occupation_field (occuDscr)
    -> values ('Software Engineer'),('Economics'),
    -> ('Structural Engineer'),('Legal Advisors'),
    -> ('Plumbers'),('Social Advisors'),('Musicians');
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create table job_post
    -> (pstOccuId int not null,pstTitle varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into job_post values
    -> (1,'Software Engineer Recruit'),
    -> (1,'Web Developer Recruit'),
    -> (7,'Saxophonist'),
    -> (5,'Construction Company looking for plumber');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.21 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

Here is the result:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     oc.occuDscr,pst.amount
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT COUNT(1) amount,pstOccuId
    ->     FROM job_post GROUP BY pstOccuId) pst
    ->     INNER JOIN occupation_field oc
    ->     ON (pst.pstOccuId = oc.occuId)
    -> ORDER BY
    ->     pst.amount DESC,oc.occuDscr
    -> ;
+-------------------+--------+
| occuDscr          | amount |
+-------------------+--------+
| Software Engineer |      2 |
| Musicians         |      1 |
| Plumbers          |      1 |
+-------------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

To get counts for all occupations, query this way:

```
SELECT 
    oc.occuDscr,IFNULL(pst.amount,0) amount
FROM
    occupation_field oc LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(1) amount,pstOccuId  
    FROM job_post GROUP BY pstOccuId) pst 
    ON (oc.occuId = pst.pstOccuId) 
ORDER BY 
    pst.amount DESC,oc.occuDscr 
;
```

Here is that result:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     oc.occuDscr,IFNULL(pst.amount,0) amount
    -> FROM
    ->     occupation_field oc LEFT JOIN
    ->     (SELECT COUNT(1) amount,pstOccuId
    ->     FROM job_post GROUP BY pstOccuId) pst
    ->     ON (oc.occuId = pst.pstOccuId)
    -> ORDER BY
    ->     pst.amount DESC,oc.occuDscr
    -> ;
+---------------------+--------+
| occuDscr            | amount |
+---------------------+--------+
| Software Engineer   |      2 |
| Musicians           |      1 |
| Plumbers            |      1 |
| Economics           |      0 |
| Legal Advisors      |      0 |
| Social Advisors     |      0 |
| Structural Engineer |      0 |
+---------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative, you can also execute the below query, brings the same result.

```
SELECT occuDscr, COUNT(occuId) AS 'amount'
 FROM occupation_field of,job_post jp
 WHERE of.occuId = jp.pstOccuId
   GROUP BY occuDscr, occuId
   ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb84b/3/0)

Comment: This is the old (before 1992) SQL syntax. Most people use `JOIN` these days. Your query is practically (and functionally) the same as a1ex07's.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube (always there)! Does this mean it might not be compatible with newer versions? Or other engines?

Comment: No, it's still in the SQL standard and allowed in all SQL products. But the `JOIN` is more flexible (you can have `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `FULL` joins, besides the `INNER` and `CROSS` joins that the old syntax allows). And it's more easy to catch errors (like a missing condition) in more complex queries.